# Are my thoughts on these two questions correct?

Tags: grammar

1-Where is jack?

2-Do you know where Jack is?

In first question, Jack is subject, and we're asking about an object.
(Jack is in the bathroom)

But in second question, our subject is "you" So Jack and the place he could be are both objects.
(Yes, I know where Jack is)(he's in the bathroom)

Is it correct if I say, "do you know" is main clause? and "where Jack is" subordinate?
Is "where" a subordinate conjunction here?

Answer (score 1):

In the second question, Jack is the subject of the subordinate clause "where Jack is".  That clause is an interrogative content clause. That clause is a complement in the structure of the main clause.

So "Jack" is not an object.  Note that if the pronoun "I" is used

> Do you know where I am?

The pronoun takes the subject form "I" and not the object form "me",  *Where me am, is ungrammatical.